# register my application via url

Tags: android

The principle is to attach a URL like: IDL://user:password
When the user click the button connect, we get identifying information and we lunch connection.

The application will be opened at the beginning of a relationship of type "idl://".

The application will be able to automatically authenticate the user whose credentials will be added to the URL as: idl://username: password.

Does any one have an idea how can i do this?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can setup an intent filter in your Manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="idl />
</intent-filter>
```

This should do the trick.